# Is there a mainstream school of thought in mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, philosophy

Some years ago(before I started studying mathematics) I was under the impression that most mathematician "believe" in Mathematical Platonism, however, the more I study the more I feel this is not really the case.

From reading and hearing different points of view about the philosophy of mathematics I see there are certain overlaps between the different schools of thought, e.g., Formalism, Deductivism and Logicism seem to be very close to one another.

Is there currently a mainstream school that most mathematicians follow?

Comment: I'd say most mathematicians are just doing math, following the established rules for defining mathematical objects and proving statements about them, and not thinking too deeply about the metaphysics of it.

Comment: if there is a mainstream thought it could be called just simplicity: to do everything as simple as possible. This mean, by example, that the logical rule of the excluded middle is universally assumed as well as the axiom of choice. This is because mathematicians are more interested in proving things than in the model of mathematics used to do it

Comment: If mathematicians are doing math just following rules wouldn't that be very similar to the instrumentalist view that some physicist hold about the interpretations of QM? Summarized in the same way by the phrase "Shut up and calculate".

Comment: I think all modern mathematicians are anti-realists to a varying degree (but not Dummettian mathematical antirealism, which demands acceptance of intuitionistic logic as the only correct logic) --- fundamentally, we *explore* a mathematical theory rather than *adopt* a mathematical theory as mind-independently and systematically true.  So for example if one day ZF set theory is shown to be inconsistent then we can jump ship to another set theory (or type theory or category theory or whatever) as foundation without losing much sleep over.

Comment: @Masacroso I'm not sure I'd completely agree with that, seeing for example, almost all presentation of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory include axioms which are clearly derivable from others (e.g., empty set from infinity and specification) so isn't as simple (i.e. parsimonious with the list of axioms) as possible.

Comment: Mathematicians are all exploring the logical consequences of various sets of axioms and various definitions. That seems to be a consistent and uncontroversial way of looking at what mathematicians are doing.

Comment: It makes no difference to me, whether abstract objects actually "exist" (whatever this means) in some platonic dimension. There is certainly no $\pi$ or $e$ or $\mathbb R$, for that matter, in nature. That doesn't make the models one uses to describe nature any less useful.

What certainly isn't mainstream is the rather tiring evangelism that math has to pertain to and only to nature without using some "infinity magic".

Comment: @user10354138 well, it makes things easier from a pedagogical point of view. Same happens for definitions of some objects as vector spaces, and so on, the axiomatic many times could be slightly redundant, but it due to pedagogical reasons, otherwise things will be to dry for a first approach

Answer (score 7):

Consider this too short to be a full answer, but too long to be a comment.

As far as I am aware, at least from my own experience, the mindset of a mathematician is always in constant flow. I would be hard-pressed to believe than any single mathematician stuck to a single philosophy throughout their career, and because of this, I see a wide variety in perspectives at any given time.

As Karl points out, *"most mathematicians are just doing math"*. I think this is an excellent point, and mutually agreeable. I'd add to this by saying that the average pure mathematician is more-so enjoying crafting theorems and discovering esoteric objects than thinking about philosophical implications perhaps in the same way an athlete simply enjoys playing the sport, rather than thinking about the politics of the sport.

## The not-so-mainstream

That being said, although it's difficult to answer what it means for something to be a mainstream school of thought in mathematics, I think most mathematicians do (perhaps unconsciously) hold very sincere opinions on some aspects. Hence, it may be easier to define what *isn't* mainstream. I.e; areas that generally have no major consensus. Here are a few examples of schools of thought that I've come across that seem to be in constant turmoil.

**1. How "real" are the reals and beyond?**

I've bared witness to huge debates on how appropriate the real numbers (and other fields) are, when it comes to both intuition, and their relation to the real world.

- Do transcendental numbers really "exist" in the real world the same way rational numbers do?
- Why did the Ancient Greeks put so much emphasis on the constructible numbers alone?
- How do we justify the [supertask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertask) that is doing arithmetic with one or more irrational numbers?
- Are complex numbers and their extensions such as the quaternions, octonions, etc, just mathematical "hacks", or do they serve a very real basis in the universe's doings.

**2. The nature of infinity**

This is an area who's controversy is hopefully self-explanatory.

- Should we think of infinity as [actual infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actual_infinity) or as an unreachable, potential infinity?
- Is there any intuition or credibility towards an infinite series having a value different than it's (potentially divergent) limit, such as in the cases of [Ramanujan summations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation) or [p-adic systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number)?

**3. What is the best foundation of mathematics?**

- Is it [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms), set theory, or something more general, such as category theory?
- Which axioms are the most intuitive?
- How do we justify the self-recursive nature of [metalanguage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalanguage)?

## The mainstream

In the most general sense, there are a few schools of thought that seem to be very agreeable, when it comes to how mathematics is done. Here are some examples.

- The [law of the excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle). Perhaps so unanimous, that we take it for granted, having it being at the heart of nearly every proof. Or more generally, the use of classical argument forms like [modus-ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens), arising from the widespread use of binary logic.
- [Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalization). We seem to love to make every proof a "special case" of even more powerful theorems.
- [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor). The formulae and notation of mathematics wouldn't be quite the same if we didn't attempt to simply everything we can. Would $e^{i\pi}=-1$ really be as beautiful if we had written it out as
  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n\sqrt{-1}\left(4\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\right)}=-1?$$

But these are just my thoughts, at least. However I do hope they provide some insight. Also, I recommend OP add the [soft-question](/questions/tagged/soft-question) tag to warrant against closure of this question.

Comment: Occam's razor is a rule of thumb for choosing between competing explanations of some phenomenon; so I don't see how the third bullet is related to Occam's razor.

Comment: @littleO this is true, and I am also sure that you understand what I am implying by evoking it here, as it has overlap (or dare I say isomorphism) here in regards to which representations of formulae are "the most pure".

Comment: I've always wondered if one can elaborate "consistent" logical frameworks where the excluded middle is replaced with a 3rd possibility where propositions are simply not provable (arguably a logical alternative to being true or false)

Comment: @lurscher In a way, that is the situation in intuitionistic logic. Not that an proposition can be "neither true nor false" (a third option), but in the sense that to prove the statement $P\,\vee\,\neg P$, you must either prove $P$, or prove $\neg P$. So unless you actually know is $P$ is true or false, you cannot assert that the law of excluded middle holds for $P$.

Comment: Somehow, you have a similar phenomenon in classical mathematics, too: by Gödel's incompleteness theorem, most axiomatic systems of interest will have propositions $P$ that are undecidable within that system (even though they in an idealistic sense satisfy $P\,\vee\,\neg P$).